# Assign to variable from parameter table PL/SQL

Tags: sql, parameters, plsql

I have a table with 4 columns (REFERENCEID,REFERENCENAME,REFERENCEVALUE,REFCOMMENT) all as VARCHAR2 datatype.

This table has 19 records. I would like to create a variable v_param and pass REFERENCEVALUE of 16th record into it.

I had a similar problem before but my old parameter table only had 1 record in it and I did

```
SELECT tbl_parameter.value INTO v_param FROM tbl_parameter
```

That worked for that problem but the teacher told us that this is a very inefficient way of assigning a value from a parameter table, he mentioned that once someone adds records to your table then you will have problems assigning the values.

This is where my problem is, the current parameter table has 19 records in it and I need to select 16th record, the values for the 16th record are:

```
REFERENCEID = REF16
REFERENCENAME = ABC
REFERENCEVALUE = 100
REFCOMMENT = NONE
```

I am thinking of doing it something like this

```
SELECT parameter.referencevalue INTO v_param FROM parameter
WHERE parameter.referenceid = 'REF16'
AND parameter.referencename = 'ABC';
```

Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The select statement you wrote is correct.

```
SELECT parameter.referencevalue INTO v_param FROM parameter
WHERE parameter.referenceid = 'REF16'
AND parameter.referencename = 'ABC';
```

You only need to specify enough criteria in the WHERE clause to make sure you return the single record you want.

For example, if the primary key in your table is REFERENCEID, then you can just use this:

```
SELECT parameter.referencevalue INTO v_param FROM parameter
WHERE parameter.referenceid = 'REF16';
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply mate, I think I will use that method unless I manage to find a different approach :)